# Make a text and select dropdown horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a text like label and select dropdown in the same line.
When I use `display: inline` for both `div`s it works. But when I use `form-control` class in select it breaks. Here is the example

[image]

Here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div> <span>test</span></div>

  <div>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it in same line.

Comment: Do you want text and `select` to be centered? Also do you want `select` to align on the right side of container?

Answer (score 5):

Add `display: flex` for container.

```css
.flex {
  /* become a flex container */
  /* its children will be flex-items */
  display: flex;
  /* align items on font's baseline */
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-2 flex">
  <div><span>test</span></div>

  <div>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex` on the container to make it's decendants become flex-items, `align-items: center` to center them, and have a `margin-right` on the label to have a nice spacing between it and the `select` element.

```css
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-2 input-container">
  <label class="input-label">test</label>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Bootstrap, always think in a Bootstrap way: I mean use its grid layout philosophy.

So you can wrap those 2 `<div>`s within a `.row`, and then use the predefined columns you need according to the available  breakpoints you want. This procedure should solve your problem:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-your_break_point_unit">
        <!-- your text here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-your_break_point_unit">
        <select>
            <!-- your select options here -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<label>Country</label>
<select>
<option>Nepal</option>
<option>India</option>
<option>China</option>
</select>
```

Note: form-horizontal class of bootstrap will keep both in the same line.